# How to define a join condition in stream-batch streaming join?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1v with java 1.8. and kafka versions spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11_2.4.3.

I am trying to join static data frame i.e. meta-data with another streaming dataframe as below:

```
 Dataset<Row> streamingDs  = //read from kafka topic
 Dataset<Row> staticDf=  //read from oracle meta-data table.


Dataset<Row> joinDf = streamingDs.as("c").join(staticDf.as("i") ,
                      "c.code = i.industry_code"
                      );
```

Even though I have respective columns data in the dataframes its giving below error.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: USING column `c.code = i.industry_code` cannot be resolved on the left side of the join. The left-side columns: [id,  tranasctionDate, companyName,code];

I tried as below:

```
Dataset<Row> joinDf = streamingDs.as("c").join(staticDf.as("i") ,
                      "c.code = i.industry_code",
                      "inner"
                      );
```

This gives below error:

> The method join(Dataset, String) in the type Dataset is not applicable for the arguments (Dataset, String, String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** `c.code = i.industry_code` is considered the name of a column to join on (not a join expression).

---

Change the code to be as follows:

```
streamingDs.as("c").join(staticDf.as("i")) // INNER JOIN is the default
  .where("c.code = i.industry_code")
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go , below code even reads latest updated dimension data for every batch but do keep in mind the new dimension data (country info in my case have to be in a new file).

```
package com.capone.streaming.BraodcastJoin

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue
import com.capone.streaming.BroadCastStreamJoin.getClass
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, ForeachWriter, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{broadcast, expr}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType, TimestampType}

object BroadCastStreamJoin2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    @transient lazy val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("com.amazonaws").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("com.amazon.ws").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("io.netty").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()

    val schemaUntyped1 = StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("id", StringType),
        StructField("customrid", StringType),
        StructField("customername", StringType),
        StructField("countrycode", StringType),
        StructField("timestamp_column_fin_1", TimestampType)
      ))

    val schemaUntyped2 = StructType(
      Array(
        StructField("id", StringType),
        StructField("countrycode", StringType),
        StructField("countryname", StringType),
        StructField("timestamp_column_fin_2", TimestampType)
      ))

    import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
    val factDf1 = spark.readStream
      .schema(schemaUntyped1)
      .option("header", "true")
      //.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)
      .csv("src/main/resources/broadcasttest/fact")

    var countrDf: Option[DataFrame] = None: Option[DataFrame]

    def readDim() = {
      val dimDf2 = spark.read
        .schema(schemaUntyped2)
        .option("header", "true")
        .csv("src/main/resources/broadcasttest/dimension")

      if (countrDf != None) {
        countrDf.get.unpersist()
      }

      countrDf = Some(
        dimDf2
          .withColumnRenamed("id", "id_2")
          .withColumnRenamed("countrycode", "countrycode_2"))

      countrDf.get.show()
    }

    factDf1.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
        batchDF.show(10)
        readDim()

        batchDF
          .join(
            countrDf.get,
            expr(
              """
      countrycode_2 = countrycode 
      """
            ),
            "leftOuter"
          )
          .show

      }
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()

  }

}
```